# How can I filter pre-aggregated data in Rmarkdown without Shiny?

Tags: r, r-markdown, reactable, crosstalk

## Original Question

### (See update with partial solution below.)

I have an RMarkdown document which summarizes how many records (rows) have various attributes by group.  I would like to be able to manipulate which records are included in the table by filtering before the summarizing.  I've created a minimal but similar mockup below.

What I would like is an interactive checkbox that would effectively "comment or uncomment" out the line

```
  # filter(weight_class == "Heavy") %>%
```

below.

I know I could do this with Shiny, but I need to be able to share the resulting HTML file with colleagues directly (through a shared Box folder in my case), so a Shiny solution is not viable, at least for now.  Also, I've considered using the features of `DT`/`datatable`, but as far as I can see the filtering needs to happen before it gets there (although I'm open to being shown I'm wrong about that).

I have seen packages like `htmltools`, `htmlwidgets`, and `crosstalk` that seem like they could facilitate this, but I'm not familiar enough with them yet and can't seem to find an example online close enough to modify for my purposes.

In actuality I have multiple conditions I would like to be able to filter on and multiple tables and plots I would like to produce from the filtered data, but I hope the minimal example below serves as a viable starting point.

How may I add such a checkbox (or similar) to create this type of interactivity without resorting to Shiny?

Demo RMarkdown:

````
---
title: "Table Demo"
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
library(tidyverse)
library(DT)
```

```{r data}
set.seed(42)
df <- tibble(
  group = sample(paste0("Group ", LETTERS[1:4]), 100, replace = T),
  weight_class = sample(c("Heavy", "Light"), 100, replace = T, prob = c(.3, .7)),
  is_ready = sample(c(TRUE, FALSE), 100, replace = T, prob = c(.4, .6))
)
```

```{r table}
df %>% 
  # filter(weight_class == "Heavy") %>% 
  count(group, is_ready) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = "is_ready", values_from = n) %>% 
  rename(Ready = `TRUE`, not_ready = `FALSE`) %>% 
  mutate(Total = Ready + not_ready, Ready_Percentage = Ready/Total) %>% 
  select(group, Ready, Total, Ready_Percentage, -not_ready) %>% 
  datatable() %>% 
  formatPercentage("Ready_Percentage")
```
````

Resulting HTML:

[image: HTML_output]

## Update with partial solution

I've got a nearly working solution from @user2554330's suggestion:

````
---
title: "Table Demo"
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
library(tidyverse)
library(DT)
```

```{r data}
set.seed(42)
df <- tibble(
  group = sample(paste0("Group ", LETTERS[1:4]), 100, replace = T),
  weight_class = sample(c("Heavy", "Light"), 100, replace = T, prob = c(.3, .7)),
  is_ready = sample(c(TRUE, FALSE), 100, replace = T, prob = c(.4, .6))
)
```

```{r solution}
library(reactable)
library(crosstalk)
shared_df <- SharedData$new(df)

shared_df %>% 
  reactable(
    groupBy = "group",
    columns = list(
      is_ready = colDef(aggregate = "frequency")
    )
  ) -> tb

bscols(
  widths = c(2, 10),
  list(filter_checkbox("weight_class", "Weight Class", shared_df, ~weight_class)),
  tb
)
```
````

Unfortunately, the filtering does not affect the aggregation (see screenshots).

#### Screenshot with All Records Selected:

[image: All Records]

#### Screenshot with Heavy Records Only Selected:

[image: Heavy Records Only]

The filtering affects the group counts but not the `is_ready` frequency aggregation.  I expect the filtering to affect this column as well, with something like this result:

```
df %>% filter(weight_class == "Heavy") %>% count(group, is_ready)
#> # A tibble: 8 x 3
#>   group   is_ready     n
#>   <chr>   <lgl>    <int>
#> 1 Group A FALSE        8
#> 2 Group A TRUE         1
#> 3 Group B FALSE        7
#> 4 Group B TRUE         3
#> 5 Group C FALSE        4
#> 6 Group C TRUE         1
#> 7 Group D FALSE       11
#> 8 Group D TRUE         2
```

<sup>Created on 2021-12-14 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You want some HTML elements to aid in filtering the data, and then you want the summarization to change based on that selection? If that's the case, then R is not going to help you here. While `datatables` (the html element) can provide some reasonable client-side filtering, it won't do summarizing for you. To do that, you'll need to write in something that will be available to the user, such as javascript.

Comment: You might be able to do this with `crosstalk` and `reactable`.  This blog post https://themockup.blog/posts/2020-05-29-client-side-interactivity-do-more-with-crosstalk/ does similar things.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try adding a JS aggregate function callback, instead of using the built-in aggregation:

```
shared_df %>% 
  reactable(
    groupBy = "group",
    columns = list(
      # is_ready = colDef(aggregate = "frequency"),
      is_ready = colDef(aggregated = JS("function(cellInfo) {
        let total_rows = cellInfo.subRows.length
        let total_ready_rows = cellInfo.subRows.filter(val => val.is_ready === true).length
        let percent = Math.round(total_ready_rows * 100 / total_rows) + '%'
        
        return percent
      }"))
    )
  ) -> tb
```

[image]
[image]

For some reason, if you use `frequency` function, or any other default one, it won't get updated, but JS always uses dynamic data; henceforth, use JS function to calculate aggregations for the filtered data.

The full code:

````
---
title: "Table Demo"
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
library(tidyverse)
library(DT)
```

```{r data}
set.seed(42)
df <- tibble(
  group = sample(paste0("Group ", LETTERS[1:4]), 100, replace = T),
  weight_class = sample(c("Heavy", "Light"), 100, replace = T, prob = c(.3, .7)),
  is_ready = sample(c(TRUE, FALSE), 100, replace = T, prob = c(.4, .6))
)
```

```{r solution}
library(reactable)
library(crosstalk)
shared_df <- SharedData$new(df)

shared_df %>% 
  reactable(
    groupBy = "group",
    columns = list(
      # is_ready = colDef(aggregate = "frequency"),
      is_ready = colDef(aggregated = JS("function(cellInfo) {
        let total_rows = cellInfo.subRows.length
        let total_ready_rows = cellInfo.subRows.filter(val => val.is_ready === true).length
        let percent = Math.round(total_ready_rows * 100 / total_rows) + '%'
        
        return percent
      }"))
    )
  ) -> tb

bscols(
  widths = c(2, 10),
  list(filter_checkbox("weight_class", "Weight Class", shared_df, ~weight_class)),
  tb
)
```
````